# groupBy first, then sort array based on name with lodash?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have some json in the form of:

```
data = { 
    "1": {"name": "eve", "type": "sergeant", "age": 22},
    "2": {"name": "bob", "type": "sergeant", "age": 33},
    "3": {"name": "bats", "type": "private", "age": 90},
    "4": {"name": "carol", "type": "captain", "age": 50},
    "5": {"name": "noogle", "type": "sergeant", "age": 34},
    "6": {"name": "good", "type": "sergeant", "age": 47},
    "7": {"name": "alice", "type": "private", "age": 34}
}
```

How can I `groupBy` their `type`, and then within each type, they are **sorted** by their name in ascending order?

I tried to do it with:

```
let grouped = _.groupBy(Object.keys(data), function(id) {
    return data[id].type;
});
```

Which will give me something like:

```
{
    "sergeant": ["1", "2", "5", "6"],
    "private": ["3", "7"],
    "captain": ["4"]
}
```

But when I try to `sortBy` it gives me the same object as above:

```
_.map(Object.keys(grouped), function(type_name) {
    grouped[type_name] = _.sortedBy(grouped[type_name], function(id) {
        return data[id].name;
    });
});
```

How can I sort the array after I've grouped the objects together? Is there a way I can cleanly chain `groupBy` and `sortBy` together instead of splitting logic like I have above?

Comment: You can't sort the keys of an object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `_.mapValues` method to sort each group after you've grouped them up by using `_.groupBy`. Just take each value and return the sorted version of it in your `_.mapValues` callback function.

Example:

```js
data = { 
    "1": {"name": "eve", "type": "sergeant", "age": 22},
    "2": {"name": "bob", "type": "sergeant", "age": 33},
    "3": {"name": "bats", "type": "private", "age": 90},
    "4": {"name": "carol", "type": "captain", "age": 50},
    "5": {"name": "noogle", "type": "sergeant", "age": 34},
    "6": {"name": "good", "type": "sergeant", "age": 47},
    "7": {"name": "alice", "type": "private", "age": 34}
}

console.log(_.mapValues(_.groupBy(data, "type"), v => _.sortBy(v, "name")))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Or, if you just want grouped and sorted keys, or grouped and sorted key/values, you can use the same approach, although its not quite as easy on the eyes:

```js
data = { 
    "1": {"name": "eve", "type": "sergeant", "age": 22},
    "2": {"name": "bob", "type": "sergeant", "age": 33},
    "3": {"name": "bats", "type": "private", "age": 90},
    "4": {"name": "carol", "type": "captain", "age": 50},
    "5": {"name": "noogle", "type": "sergeant", "age": 34},
    "6": {"name": "good", "type": "sergeant", "age": 47},
    "7": {"name": "alice", "type": "private", "age": 34}
}

// If all you want are grouped and sorted keys:
console.log(_.mapValues(_.groupBy(_.keys(data), k => data[k].type), v => _.sortBy(v, i => data[i].name)))

// Or for grouped and sorted keys and values:
console.log(_.mapValues(_.groupBy(_.keys(data), k => data[k].type), v => _.sortBy(v, i => data[i].name).map(k => ({[k]: data[k]}))))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is there a way to preserve their given `ids`? ie, `"captain": [ { "4": { "name": "carol" .... } }]`;

Comment: Sure, see the second snippet. It's not as pretty or short, but it does give you the format you mentioned.